# How to execute this Stored Procedure in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, exec, calling-convention

```
   EXEC USP_USER_INSERT (P_ID = '2', P_FIRST_NAME = 'A', P_LAST_NAME = 'BALAJI', P_SALARY = '50000', P_CITY = 'CHENNAI');

EXEC USP_USER_INSERT @P_ID = '2', @P_FIRST_NAME = 'A', @P_LAST_NAME = 'BALAJI', @P_SALARY = '50000', @P_CITY = 'CHENNAI';

Both are showing error, how to call this SP.








create or replace procedure USP_USER_INSERT 
    ( 
      P_FIRST_NAME in varchar default null,
      P_LAST_NAME  in varchar default null, 
      P_SALARY   in   number default null, 
      P_CITY      in  varchar default null, 
      P_EMAIL_ID  in  varchar default null, 
      P_EMP_ID   in   number default null, 
      P_ADDED_BY  in  number default null, 
      P_WINDOWS_ID in varchar2 default null, 
      P_USER_TYPE  in number default null, 
      P_PASSWORD  in  varchar2 default null, 
      P_ROLE     in   varchar2 default null,
      RES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) 
    as 
    P_ID NUMBER;
      begin 

      select NVL(max(ID),0)+1 into P_ID from USER_MASTER ;

          insert into USER_MASTER 
                      (
                        ID,FIRST_NAME, 
                        LAST_NAME, 
                        SALARY, 
                        CITY, 
                        EMAIL_ID, 
                        EMP_ID, 
                        ADDED_ON, 
                        ADDED_BY, 
                        WINDOWS_ID, 
                        IS_ACTIVE, 
                        USER_TYPE, 
                        PASSWORD, 
                        role
                       ) 
          values      ( 
                        P_ID,P_FIRST_NAME, 
                        P_LAST_NAME, 
                        P_SALARY, 
                        P_CITY, 
                        P_EMAIL_ID, 
                        P_EMP_ID, 
                        Systimestamp, 
                        P_ADDED_BY, 
                        P_WINDOWS_ID, 
                        1, 
                        P_USER_TYPE, 
                        P_PASSWORD, 
                        P_ROLE
                      );

      open RES for
      SELECT P_ID "P_ID" FROM DUAL;                    

      END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a cursor bind variable and then wrap the procedure call in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  USP_USER_INSERT (
    P_EMP_ID     => '2',      -- P_ID is not an argument to the procedure
    P_FIRST_NAME => 'A',
    P_LAST_NAME  => 'BALAJI',
    P_SALARY     => '50000',
    P_CITY       => 'CHENNAI',
    RES          => :cur
  );
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

Comment: Is my sp correct can i able to store the new user in the table by calling it??

Comment: @karan I have not tried to compile it but I cannot see anything that would obviously cause it to fail to compile. The easiest way to check is to try to compile it and let the database tell you about any errors using `SHOW ERRORS;`.

Comment: @karan Your way should work but I would do things slightly differently and use a sequence to generate the next `id` number and would not return a cursor but just return the id using an `OUT` parameter.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "OUT" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol "." was substituted for "OUT" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

CUR
------

Comment: @karan Updated - have you tried debugging it yourself?

Comment: my requirement is to execute the SP and create a new user in the table.. i am getting the above error while executing what you said.. thanks for your intrest in sharing.. please try to help in this issue also.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### try this

> Procedure has not return value, if you need you can use function

```
exec USP_USER_INSERT ( par1,par2,....)
```

Comment: Error starting at line : 2 in command -
EXEC USP_USER_INSERT (P_ID = '2', P_FIRST_NAME = 'AZHAKU', P_LAST_NAME = 'BALAJI', P_SALARY = '50000', P_CITY = 'CHENNAI')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 24:
PLS-00201: identifier 'P_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action

Comment: p_id is not parameter that you should send.

Comment: tried without sending p_id also and still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

if you are running it on command line, you should have / at the end of sql code.

try this use single quotes if 2 is of varchar else leave as it is,
EXEC USP_USER_INSERT '2','A','BALAJI','50000','CHENNAI'

Comment: I am asking about how to call or execute that procedure.  thanks.

Comment: tried this already-- getting pl/sql compilation error.. Is my sp correct can i able to store the new user in the table by calling it??